# Find a matrix with determinant equals to $\det{(A)}\det{(D)}-\det{(B)}\det{(C)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assume I have 4 matrices $A,B,C,D\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I want to build a matrix $E\in\Bbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that:

$$\det{(E)}=\det{(A)}\det{(D)}-\det{(B)}\det{(C)}$$

under the following assumptions:

1. $m$ can be any number we want, but I prefer $2n$.
2. $E$ should not contain the terms $\det{(A)},\det{(B)},\det{(C)},\det{(D)}$. that means that the matrix 
   $\begin{pmatrix}
   \det{(A)} & \det{(B)} \\
   \det{(C)} & \det{(D)}
   \end{pmatrix}
   $ is not the case...
3. There can't be any further assumptions on $A,B,C,D$

I've already checked the matrix 
$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$
but it's not that...

Does anyone have an idea what $E$ can be?

Comment: The matrix you chose works if either $A$ or $D$ commutes with either $B$ or $C$.

Comment: Why not the $1\times 1$ matrix $(\det(E))$, or $k\times k$ $\mathrm{diag}(\det(E) \, 1 \, \ldots \,1)$?

Comment: By the way, is there any particular motivation for this question?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I need it in order to classify cetain kind of matrices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is wrong, as indicated by the comments below.

---

Let $M \oplus N$ denote the block-diagonal matrix 
$$
M \oplus N = \pmatrix{M&0\\0&N}
$$
Then one solution with $m = 4n$ is
$$
E = \pmatrix{A \oplus I & I \oplus B\\I \oplus C & D \oplus I}
$$
where $I$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Did you mean $E = \pmatrix{A \oplus0 &0\oplus B\\ 0\oplus C &D\oplus0}$?

Comment: @user1551 I did not.  Did I miscalculate?  I believe yours yields $\det(E) = \pm \det(A)\det(B)\det(C)\det(D)$.

Comment: @user1551 note that $(A \oplus I)$ commutes with $(I \oplus B)$.

Comment: I did miscalculate, but your $E$ doesn't sound right. As the top two blocks commute, $\det(E)=\det\left[(D\oplus I)(A\oplus I)-(I\oplus C)(I\oplus B)\right]=\det((DA-I)\oplus (I-CB))$.

Comment: @user1551 oh darn, that was a pretty bad oversight.  Hopefully there's a fix

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be the product of the diagonal entries of $A$ and the diagonal entries of $D$, let $t$ be the product of the diagonal entries of $B$ and the diagonal entries of $C$ and consider 
the $m\times m$ matrix $E=\begin{pmatrix}\det{(A)}\det{(D)}-\det{(B)}\det{(C)}-s+t&s-t\\-1&1\\&&1\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&1\end{pmatrix}$. 
Notice that you can pick **any** $m$, as long as it is at least $2$.

Answer (score 0):

When $m=1$, clearly what you ask for is impossible in general.

When $m\ge2$, let $a=\det(A), b=\det(B), c=\det(C), d=\det(D)$ and $e=\det(AD)-\det(BC)$. There are two cases:

1. If $e=0$, take $E$ to be $x$ times the all-one matrix for any sufficiently large $x>0$.
2. If $e\ne0$, let $S_m$ be the [symmetric Pascal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) of size $m$, which is a positive integer matrix of determinant 1 and whose first row is a row of ones. Now, any sufficiently large $x>0$, we have $x>a,b,c,d$ and $\frac{e}{x^{m-1}}\ne a,b,c,d$. Therefore we may take
   $$
   E=\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{e}{x^{m-1}},x,x,\ldots,x\right)\,S.
   $$