# Construct a matrix $M$ from $A$ and $B$ such that $\det(M)=\det(A)-\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given two $n \times n$ symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, is there a generic way to construct a larger block matrix $M$ such that $\det(M) = \det(A) - \det(B)$?

A simple block expression is desired, in the sense that the block components of $M$ are constant matrices or obtained by solving matrix equations involving $A$ and $B$.  Constructions of $M$ involving short algebraic expressions for its components in terms of the components of $A$ and $B$ would also be interesting, but not something that expands to an exponential number of terms in the components of $A$ and $B$ like just sticking $\det(A)$ in as a term of $M$.

If this is not possible in the general case, what restrictions can be placed on $A$ and $B$ to make this possible?

The only case I know of is when the difference of $B$ and $A$ can be written as a product of a column vector $C$ and its transpose: $B-A = CC^T$. This allows us to construct a matrix $M$ such that:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} A & C \\ C^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ \det(M) = \det(A) - \det(A + CC^T) = \det(A) - \det(B) $$

I'm curious if there is some way to construct an appropriate block matrix to make this possible for arbitrary symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$.

The first comment to this question
[Find a matrix with determinant equals to $\det{(A)}\det{(D)}-\det{(B)}\det{(C)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834227/find-a-matrix-with-determinant-equals-to-deta-detd-detb-detc)
suggests the answer is trivial by choosing
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ I & I \end{bmatrix}$$
but that doesn't appear to work when I tried some numerical examples.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}\det A-\det B&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is not very helpful, because not only does it merely write the answer as a single scalar (there or no properties of the matrix M that can be explored or exploited), but also for arbitrary $n \times n$ matrices it would require writing out an exponential number of terms using the components of $A$ and $B$. I was hoping for a simpler and more insightful block solution.

Comment: I think Hagen's comment can be taken as suggesting that you have to think through your question a little more deeply and work out exactly what it is that you want (and then edit the question so it asks what you really want to ask).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay, I edited and tried to add more detail, but I feel disappointed that people are still upvoting Hagen's answer. What is not clear now? Even in the original post it's not like I failed to give context for what I meant by constructing a block matrix from A and B. I gave one explicit example, and listed one attempted answer extracted from a user's comment (from a question which gave even more context). If someone has a better suggestion for terminology or wording, feel free to edit.

Comment: $\det(M)=\det(A-B)$, by Schur complement formula, which is why you're getting a different result.